# Symfony2 composer.phar install

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Hi i want to install this bundle:

https://packagist.org/packages/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle

```
"knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.3.*@dev"
```

But i dont want to screw something with composer.phar update because last time it killed some bundles functions in FOS bundle when i remember right.

So i did only::

```
sudo php composer.phar install
```

But i got this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.1.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.1.x-dev].
    - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.1.x-dev requires knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle 2.3.*@dev -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

And these are my requirements for symfony and php. It should be enough right? What's the problem then please?

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
```

Answer (score 0):

try "minimum-stability": "dev"

see: http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md

Comment: you mean? "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev" i already tried it, did not work.

Answer (score 0):

add the following line in your composer and update composer

"knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master"

Answer (score 0):

I got the same. Then I tried to use **php composer.phar update** and it works.

Hope this will help!